# Understanding "except for a tension in his right wrist that spread down through his hand and all the way up his forearm"

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Breathing deep, he relaxed his whole body, except for a tension in his right wrist that spread down through his hand and all the way up his forearm.

Please help me to understand the above sentence. I can not get it from the word "except" begins.

Comment: The sentence says that, unlike the rest of his body, which he relaxed, there was a tension in his right wrist. This tension then moved (spread) down from the wrist, through his hand to the tips of his fingers. At the same time the tension moved up from the wrist, through the forearm to his elbow. Therefore, there was a tension in his right hand, wrist, and forearm.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you confused by specific words or by the grammatical structure?  What research have you done to try to understand this sentence?

Comment: The only part of his body that was tense was his wrist. (At least at first. At some point, the tension spread from his wrist to his hand and forearm.) If you're wondering how it's possible to relax all parts of a body but for one—that's not an issue with grammar.

Answer (score 1):

He relaxed his whole body, except his wrist. He was tense from his hand to his forearm.